# How to set where condition globally on model in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, query-builder

I am fething Data from database with the help of this query

```
Staff::where('active',1)->get()
```

I am using this query in many places in my project is it possible to use this where condition globally?
in the model so I don't have to change it everywhere

Answer (score 1):

You can use [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#query-scopes) for that. Check this doc ;) This is your [example](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes)

Comment: But here is one problem with it. Doesn't work when i use find(1) . if i i want it intentionally  it is coming out

Answer (score 0):

**In Staff Model :-**

```
class Staff extends Model
{
    public function scopeActive($q)
    {
        return $q->where('is_active','y');
    }

}
```

**In Controller:-**

```
$staffs= Staff::active()->get();

$staff= Staff::active()->find(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Global Scope:

```
<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;

class ActiveScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder->where('active', 1);
    }
}
```

In Your Model :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Scopes\ActiveScope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Staff extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new ActiveScope);
    }
}
```

Or You Can Use Local scope Query :

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
    class Staff extends Model
    {
         
       public function scopeActive($query)
       {
          return $query->where('active',1);
       }
    }
```

In Your Controller :

```
Staff::active()->get();
```